# Feed-Forward Neural Network - XOR Learning Very Slowly

Tags: java, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I've recently been attempting to make a feed-forward neural network from scratch. It's been able to learn the XOR function, although it takes way more epochs than described by other people.

My network uses a learning rate of 0.25, no momentum, and the activation function is the sigmoid function. (1/(1+e^-x))

I have read before that training with the MNIST database only takes 1k epochs or so. However, for something as simple as XOR, it takes maybe 100k epochs (a couple of seconds) for my network to get within 0.05 of the correct answer for XOR.

For example, for 1,0 the NN will output 0.96.

It does eventually train, but for some reason it's taking many times more epochs than described.

So my question is: Why is my network taking so long? I suspect it has to do with the back propagation, although I don't know how to verify that.

The entire project can be seen [here on github.](https://github.com/coolioasjulio/Java-Simple-Neural-Network/blob/master/src/neuralnetwork/NeuralNetwork.java)

Forward pass:

```
private double evaluate(double[] input){
    //reset the neuron values
    for(NeuronLayer layer:layers){
        for(Neuron neuron:layer.getNeurons()){
            neuron.weightedSum = 0;
        }
    }

    //set the output of the input neurons to the input
    for(int i = 0; i < layers[0].getNeurons().length; i++){
        layers[0].getNeurons()[i].output = input[i];
    }

    //cycle through all the neurons
    for(int i = 0; i < layers.length; i++){
        for(Neuron neuron:layers[i].getNeurons()){
            if(i != 0) neuron.activationFunction(); //apply the activation function if not an input neuron
            if(i != layers.length - 1){
                for(Dendrite dendrite:neuron.getDendrites()){
                    //Increment the weightedSum of the destination neuron by the source neuron output scaled by the weight
                    dendrite.getEnd().weightedSum += neuron.output * dendrite.weight;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    double result = layers[layers.length-1].getNeurons()[0].weightedSum; //return the output of the first output neuron.
    return result;
}
```

Getting neuron errors:

```
void getErrors(double result, double expectedResult){
    for(int i = layers.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
        NeuronLayer layer = layers[i];
        for(int j = 0; j < layer.getNeurons().length; j++){
            Neuron neuron = layer.getNeurons()[j];
            double neuronError = 0;
            if(i == layers.length - 1){
                neuronError = neuron.getDerivative() * (result - expectedResult);
            }
            else{
                neuronError = neuron.getDerivative();

                double sum = 0;
                for(Dendrite dendrite:neuron.getDendrites()){
                    sum += dendrite.weight * dendrite.getEnd().getError();
                }
                neuronError *= sum;
            }
            neuron.setError(neuronError);
        }
    }
}
```

Updating weights based on error:

```
void updateWeights(HashMap<Dendrite,Double> dendriteDeltaMap, double learningRate, double momentum){
    for(int i = layers.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
        NeuronLayer layer = layers[i];
        for(Neuron neuron:layer.getNeurons()){
            for(Dendrite dendrite:neuron.getInputs()){
                double delta = learningRate * neuron.getError() * dendrite.getStart().getOutput();
                if(dendriteDeltaMap.get(dendrite) != null){
                    delta += momentum * dendriteDeltaMap.get(dendrite);
                }
                dendriteDeltaMap.put(dendrite, delta);
                dendrite.adjustWeight(-delta);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Training function:

```
public void train(double[][] inputs, double[] outputs, double learningRate, double momentum, int maxIterations){
    int runs = 0;
    double startError = 0;
    while(true){
        HashMap<Dendrite,Double> dendriteDeltaMap = new HashMap<>();
        double errorSum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
            double sum = evaluate(inputs[i]);//get sum
            double result = sigmoid(sum); //calculate final result
            double error = Math.pow(outputs[i]-result,2)/2; //calculate mean squared error
            errorSum += error;
            //System.out.println("Error: " + error);
            getErrors(result, outputs[i]);
            updateWeights(dendriteDeltaMap, learningRate, momentum);
        }
        double avgError = errorSum/inputs.length;
        if(runs == 0) startError = avgError;
        System.out.println("Epoch: " + runs + ", error: " + avgError);
        runs++;
        if(runs>=maxIterations || avgError <= Math.pow(0.03, 2)/2) break;
    }
    System.out.println("\nFinished!");
    System.out.println("Start error: " + startError);
    printWeights();
}
```

Comment: I think you should use a momentum. Without momentum you don't consider the previous weights at all and purely the error and the learning rate defines the new weight. Furthermore 0.25 may be a bit high for learning rate. The higher the learning rate results longer training time because the training process is converging slower. In my understanding these 2 reasons makes your training working similar to random walk. I would try a learning rate 0.1 and a momentum 0.9.

Comment: I have same results with XOR as you. I used topology 2 2 1 and time duration was 50 000 cycles. I run network again and again. So, starting value of weights affect the error by lot. Good starting point leads to faster convergence. And also XOR is trivial problem for us, but for network XOR can be big issue.

Comment: @Manngo I changed the learning rate to 0.1, and implemented momentum similar to what [this person did.](https://github.com/vivin/DigitRecognizingNeuralNetwork/blob/master/src/main/java/net/vivin/neural/Backpropagator.java) However, I'm still getting the same results. It still takes 10k epochs for the network to get withing 0.05 of the correct answer for XOR. I've edited the code in the question (specifically the weight update and training method) to show the new code. Did I implement it correctly?